# SyntaxError in virtual environment with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenvwrapper

I have pip installed the virtualenvwrapper in my Ubuntu 14.04 and when I make a new virtual environment, regardless of the version of python I think I pick, I get Python 3 in the virtualenv. For example, if I:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 newvirenv
```

When I use ipython in the terminal and try to do a print statement in the python 2 way, like:

```
print "Hello world"
```

I get:

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

I've already tried to install ipython in the virtualenv as well but that does not work either. I checked /usr/bin/ and the interpreter is there!
What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have anaconda installed. But now I always install modules via pip.

Comment: The executable is clearly there, as otherwise you'd see `The executable ... does not exist`. If you run `/usr/bin/python2.7 --version` what does that tell you? Are you sure you're using that virtualenv in IPython? How did you configure it?

Comment: When I run that I get `Python 2.7.6`. To install ipython I used `pip install ipython` (not sure if this is what you meant)

Comment: It suddenly worked

Answer (score 0):

I was probably doing something wrong when installing ipython in the virtual environment. Doing:

```
pip install ipython
```

Inside the virtual environment should work. Thanks jonrsharpe